# Diophantine equations odd and even

Tags: number-theory

my equation is $7^x + 317^y = z^2$. I have solved this equation into cases . We only consider the case when x is odd since $7 = 4 *1+3$.
So, we let$ x = 2k + 1$ for some non-negative integer k and suppose Eq.has a
solution in non-negative integers. We have $7^{2k}+1 +317^y = z^2$. We divide $y$ into two cases.
Case(i)$ y$ is even, say $y = 2n$, for some non-negative integer $n$. Then we
have, $(z + 317^n)(z - 317^n) = 7^x$. Letting $u + v = x$ and $v > u$, we obtain
$2 * 317^n = 7^v- 7^u$. So, $u = 0$ and $2*317^n = 7^{2k+1} - 1$. This is contradiction
because $7^{2k+1} - 1 is\equiv   0 (mod 3)$ and $2\cdot 317n  1; 2 (mod 3)$. Thus, Eq. is impossible for positive even integer x.
Case(ii) $y$ is odd i.e $y = 2n + 1$, for some non-negative integer $n$. We assume that $ z = 2m$, for some natural number $m$. Hence, $ 7^{2k + 1} + 301\cdot317^{2n} = 4m^2 - 16\cdot317^{2n} $   or $ 7( 7^{2k} + 43\cdot317^{2n}) = 4( m - 2\cdot317^n)(m + 2\cdot317^n)$. It follows that $ 4( m + 2\cdot317^n) = 7^{2k} + 43\cdot317^{2n} $ and $ m - 2\cdot317^n = 7 $. This gives us the values $n = 0$, $k = 0$ and $m = 9$. Thus, we obtain the only solution $(x, y, z) = (1, 1, 18)$ to the Diophantine equation  $ 7^x + 317^y = z^2 $.\
Here i want to ask  $ 4( m + 2\cdot317^n) = 7^{2k} + 43\cdot317^{2n} $ and $ m - 2\cdot317^n = 7 $ is true?

Comment: Side note: press 'Enter' twice at the end of each statement if you want people to be able to actually read your question.

Comment: $$\{7^x + {317}^y = z^2\} \land \{x = 2k + 1\}$$ does not imply $$7^{2k} + 1 + {317}^y = z^2$$

Comment: Simulposted to MO, without notice to either site – please, don't do that. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/247508/diophantine-equation-problem